# insertmacro is getting called twice

Tags: nsis

Hi I have below code in place

file: setup.nsi

```
Function .onInit
    Call functionXXX
FunctionEnd
```

File: Utils.nsh

```
!define someFunc "!insertmacro someFunc"
!macro someFunc source destination
    MessageBox "${source}, ${destination}"
!macroend 


Function functionXXX
    ${someFunc} "C:\MyApp\test.txt" "C:\MyApp\backup\test.txt"
FunctionEnd
```

If I run the script, macro being called twice, I am seeing the message box twice with same values. Why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way this code as posted here will MessageBox twice.

There has to be some other code calling it, try:

```
Function .onInit
    Messagebox mb_ok before
    Call functionXXX
    Messagebox mb_ok after
FunctionEnd
```

You should also be able to see all the steps in the compiler output...

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out, I was calling it on of the Section.